# WooCommerce Custom Attributes

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am developing a website for optical showroom. They want a website like lenskart.com. Not on huge scale but something like that according to its features. So i want to know how to add custom selection of lens type on a popup modal and add some prescription so that admin can work according to it.

So the concept is basically like this:

User select the product - DONE
User select lens power - DONE

Now i want a logic that if user select lens power that needs to select which type of lens user needs.

For example if user selects single vision, then what type of lens he needs, anti-glare, simple lens, and both options should have checkbox of scratch resistant coating which should add some value to card if checked.

Please help!!!